# paperclip rails get extension from base64 image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I know that paperclip gem automatically detects base64 data and turn it to image, but the saved file name is '**data?12345**' (without any extension), even though the base64 starts with

```
data:image/png;base64,iV...IlNJZUPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

in which I can see clearly that the extension should be .png

Is there any way to tell paperclip to add the extension from base64 data?

Answer (score 0):

my workaround is to appoint an extension to the formats, so no need to worry about the original extension.

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :original => ["400x400>",:jpg]}
```

it's not perfect but works for me.